# Stop clock that starts out green and changes to yellow at 5 minutes then changes again to red after 10

Tags: python, tkinter

So I need a stop clock that the background of the user interface starts out green then turns to yellow after 5 minutes, then it changes to red after 10 minutes. I am using a Tkinter GUI and the source code from: [Create a stopwatch using python](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/create-stopwatch-using-python/).

Here are my modifications to the code

```
#importing the required libraries 
import tkinter as Tkinter 
from datetime import datetime 
counter = 9000000
running = False
def counter_label(label): 
    def count(): 
        if running: 
            global counter 
    
            # To manage the intial delay. 
            if counter==9000000:             
                display="Starting..."
            else: 
                tt = datetime.fromtimestamp(counter) 
                string = tt.strftime("%H:%M:%S") 
                display=string 
    
            label.config(text=display) 
    
            # label.after(arg1, arg2) delays by 
            # first argument given in milliseconds 
            # and then calls the function given as second argument. 
            # Generally like here we need to call the 
            # function in which it is present repeatedly. 
            # Delays by 1000ms=1 seconds and call count again. 
            label.after(1000, count) 
            counter += 1
    
    # Triggering the start of the counter. 
    count()  
    
# start function of the stopwatch 
def Start(label): 
    global running 
    running=True
    counter_label(label) 
    start['state']='disabled'
    stop['state']='normal'
    reset['state']='normal'
    
# Stop function of the stopwatch 
def Stop(): 
    global running 
    start['state']='normal'
    stop['state']='disabled'
    reset['state']='normal'
    running = False
    
# Reset function of the stopwatch 
def Reset(label): 
    global counter 
    counter=9000000
    
    # If rest is pressed after pressing stop. 
    if running==False:   
        reset['state']='disabled'
    
    # If reset is pressed while the stopwatch is running. 
    else:                
        label['text']='Starting...'
    
root = Tkinter.Tk() 
root.title("Stopwatch") 
    

    
# Fixing the window size. 
root.minsize(width=500, height=300) 
label = Tkinter.Label(root, text=" ", fg="black", font="Verdana 200 bold") 
label.pack() 
f = Tkinter.Frame(root) 
start = Tkinter.Button(f, text='Start', width=6, command=lambda:Start(label),font="Verdana 50 bold") 
stop = Tkinter.Button(f, text='Stop',width=6,state='disabled', command=Stop,font="Verdana 50 bold") 
reset = Tkinter.Button(f, text='Reset',width=6, state='disabled', command=lambda:Reset(label),font="Verdana 50 bold") 
f.pack(anchor = 'center',pady=5) 
start.pack(side="left") 
stop.pack(side ="left") 
reset.pack(side="left") 
root.configure(bg='red')

root.mainloop()
```

Most of what I did was trim down some unnecessary parts and changed 1 or 2 small things. I'm unsure how to make the background color change automatically with the time. I believe it would be simple to do by adding an `if` statement that says when the timer is less then 5 minutes then `root.configure(bg='green')`.

However I'm unsure what variable per se is actually changing with the stop clock.

Comment: _"However I'm unsure what variable per se is actually changing with the stop clock."_ If you mean what variable contains the time that is displayed on the clock, all you need to do is look for the line of code that _sets the displayed text_

Comment: The `count()` function nested within the `counter_label()` function is watching and changing the `global counter` variable — if that is what you are asking (it's unclear).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the color change to your counter loop and use the `counter` to change the color:

```
        if counter==9000000:             
            display="Starting..."
        else: 
            tt = datetime.fromtimestamp(counter) 
            string = tt.strftime("%H:%M:%S") 
            display=string 
            if counter > 9000600:  # 10 minutes
               root.configure(bg='red')
            elif counter > 9000300:  # 5 minutes
               root.configure(bg='yellow')

       .......

root.configure(bg='green')   # start green

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: That's perfect! Not sure why I struggled with that :) Thank you so much!!!!!!!